# Just cloned a 128GB SSD into a 256GB SSD, extended the partition, but Windows keeps saying it's 128GB

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, ssd, disk-space

I wanted to upgrade my 128GB SSD in my Windows laptop into a 256GB, so I:

- Removed the 128GB SSD and connected it to a desktop computer running
  Linux
- Connected the new 256GB SSD to the same computer
- ran sudo dd if=/dev/ of=/dev/ bs=16MB status=progress
- opened GParted, tried to extend the 128GB allocated space to the whole drive on the new SSD but had to move first a small partition of
  700MB+ to the right-hand of the partition before doing so. Note
  GParted told me the GPT was corrupted and repaired it.
- Disconnected the new SSD and connected it in the laptop
- Successfully booted Windows, everything's fine except:

Windows explorer is still saying there is only 128GB capacity, whereas Easeus seems to indicate the disk is fully allocated:
[image]
[image]

(sorry for the bad quality, I'm writing this from another computer ; it was easier this way and I did not know the snaps would turn out so bad)

P.S: Yes I've seen similar threads, but they are apprently not the same issue.

Comment: What about using Ghost or Acronis or like which will do what you want. We put bigger drives in client computers to accomplish this

Comment: This is likely a compatibility issue with GParted and Windows.  I would have used Windows to extend a Windows partition

Comment: don't capture screenshots by a camera like that. Use the print screen key instead